# Authentication for Bigquery using bigrquery from an R Markdown document

Tags: r, authentication, google-bigquery, bigrquery

I am having problems using `bigrquery` to connect to a GCP service account from within an R Markdown document that I knit. When I attempt from the console, authentication works fine. Both

```
library(bigrquery)
bq_auth()
```

and

```
library(bigrquery)
bq_auth(email="my-service-account-email@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
```

launch a browser with a dialog that lets me pick and authenticate using the specified account as expected. But in the R Markdown, any attempt like

```
options("httr_oob_default" = TRUE)
bq_auth(email="my-service-account-email@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
```

or even using the full list like this

```
bq_auth(
  email = "my-service-account-email@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  path = NULL,
  scopes = c("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"),
  cache = gargle::gargle_oauth_cache(),
  use_oob = gargle::gargle_oob_default(),
  token = NULL
)
```

leads to the error

```
Error: Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running bigrquery in a non-interactive session? Consider:
  * Call `bq_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
```

Can anyone see what I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the JSON file of your Google Cloud service account, then use it as a path that the “bq_auth” function can recognize. Here's the steps:

1. Google Cloud Console (console.cloud.google.com)
2. Navigation Menu
3. IAM & Admin Service
4. Accounts
5. Create Service Account (create one)
6. Create Key, and save to "/path/to/jsonfilename.json"
7. Authenticate in your R Markdown code: `bigrquery::bq_auth(path = "/path/to/jsonfilename.json")`

Note: you'll need to make sure to set the service account to have access to BigQuery.  I set mine to "BigQuery Admin" and it worked, but that might be too broad

Borrowed this answer from Elaine See's post on medium: https://medium.com/@elaine.yl.see/easiest-way-to-use-bigquery-in-r-8af466cd55ca

Comment: also, see the "Authentication and Authorization" section here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigrquery/readme/README.html

Comment: thanks Brent! can validate that this answer works. I had wrangled it a long time ago but forgot that the question was on here. Appreciate the clear articulation.

Comment: now the internet will have these instructions for future use!  glad to help